# How to fix scratches on dining table

Tags: wood, wooden-furniture

See attached picture of my dining table surface. How can I fix scratches (shown by red arrows) and make it look new again ?

Do I need to stain it again ?

[image]

Comment: How deep are the scratches?  What is top made of, real wood or fake(just a thin covering)?

Comment: I highly recommend visiting [woodworking.se] to look at the refinishing questions there. There is a _ton_ of info and expertise available there, and you'll probably find your question has been answered at least a half-dozen times.

Comment: i would try a set of furniture markers first. Might just be that $5 and 10mins of coloring will produce a result good enough for you without a lot of effort or expense. If you can get the look right, apply a new coat of poly, polycrylic, or (my fav) acrylic clear coat to seal in the color and help prevent wear and water rings in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to look like new, you're in for some work. You'll need to sand it down completely. Those orbital sanders work well for this but you'll need a hand sander for the fine grit. Start out with a medium grit,150, and finish off with 250 to 300. Thoroughly clean off and then apply the stain, looks like walnut. Then apply at least three or more coats of polyurethane. You'll have to decide the sheen level you want. Follow the directions on the cans of stain and polyurethane that you decide to use.

Comment: Looks like 20yo patina that never even had stain. I'd hate to have it look like new. I'd skip sanding it and go straight to *'Thoroughly clean off. apply stain. three or more coats of polyurethane.'* You can see how it will look w/o stain (and just poly) if you wipe it with mineral spirits. Prob be white streaks. W/e stain you use, go darker rather than lighter.